# Individual score contributions in ML estimation

Tags: stata

I've estimated a model via maximum likelihood in Stata and was surprised to find that estimated standard errors for one particular parameter are drastically *smaller* when clustering observations. I take it from the [Stata manual](http://www.stata.com/manuals13/p_robust.pdf) on robust standard error estimation in ML that this can happen if the contributions of individual observations to the score (the derivative of the log-likelihood) tend to cancel each other within clusters.

I would now like to dig a little deeper into what exactly is happening and would therefore like to have a look at these score contributions. As far as I can see, however, Stata only gives me the total sum as `e(gradient)`. Is there any way to pry the individual summands out of Stata?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have written your own command, you can create a new variable containing these scores using the [ml score](http://www.stata.com/help.cgi?ml_score) command. Official Stata commands and most finished user written commands will often have `score` as an option for `predict`, which does the same thing but with an easier syntax.

These will give you the score of the log likelihood ($\ell$) with respect to the linear predictor, $x\beta = \beta_0 + \beta_1 x_1 + \beta_2 x_2 \elipses$. To get the derivative of the log likelihood with respect to an individual parameter, say $\beta_1$, you just use the chain rule:

$\frac{\partial \ell}{\partial \beta_1} = \frac{\partial \ell }{\partial x\beta} \frac{\partial x\beta}{\partial \beta_1}$

The scores returned by Stata are $ \frac{\partial \ell }{\partial x\beta}$, and $\frac{\partial x\beta}{\partial \beta_1} = x_1$.

So, to get the score for $\beta_1$ you just multiply the score returned by Stata and $x_1$.

Comment: I must be misunderstanding something. I have n observations and my model has k parameters. The object I am looking for therefore has dimension k x n (the derivative of the individual likelihoods w.r.t the entire parameter vector. What `ml score` returns, as far as I can tell, is merely n-dimensional. Are the scores thus returned the sums of the individual gradients?

Comment: The scores are for the linear predictors, i.e. xb. You can use the chain rule to compute the scores for the individual parameters.

Comment: Could you hum me a few more bars on how I would go about doing that?